# How do I install Imagick on C9.io: an online IDE?

Tags: php, ide, cloud9-ide

I've tried out various things, yet have not found out how to make it work.

Comment: If that "workspace" is an Ubuntu server, just install the according distro package through the terminal.

Comment: Something like: `sudo apt-get install imagick`. You can search for packages using `apt-cache search imagick` to see which one you want.

Comment: Ha! It tells you how to do this on [the home page](https://c9.io/) - it seems to be `imagemagick`, not `imagick`.

Comment: @halfer I tried that, but for some reason I get "Fatal error: Class 'Imagick' not found in...", even though doing "sudo apt-get install imagick" or "sudo apt-get install php5-imagick" says it's already the newest version.

Comment: Have you tried `php -m` to see what is installed? Is your PHP code to run on the console or in a web browser? They are often two different php.ini configurations.

Comment: @halfer I've just tried now, and imagick is on the list. And my PHP code does not run on console, but uses a webpage, I've seen some topics about putting something along the lines of "extension=imagick..", cannot remember exactly, but somehow like that. What should I do?

Comment: OK. From what I recall, `imagick` being on the list means it will work in PHP's console environment, but you need to check it will work in the web environment too. Try running this script on your C9 localhost, call it `info.php`: `<?php phpinfo();`. Look for Imagick or similar in the loaded modules list.

Comment: If it is not there, you may just need to reload your web server: `sudo service apache2 reload` and try again.

Comment: Additional `sudo apt-get install php5-imagick` will do the trick.

Answer (score 8):

I was looking for a solution to this as well. I posted [this question](https://community.c9.io/t/add-imagemagick-module-to-my-php-workspace/3093/2) on the Cloud9 Community about it. Thanks to information from there and from here, I finally got it working in my C9 workspace. :)

Here are the steps that worked for me:

**1. Update apt-get packages inside the C9 terminal**

```
$ sudo apt-get update
```

**2. Install imagemagick command-line tools via apt-get**

```
$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick
```

**3. Install php5-imagick module via apt-get**

```
$ sudo apt-get install php5-imagick
```

You can then confirm the php5-imagick module is installed with:

```
$ php -m
```

Answer (score 4):

I see the answer here kinda broken into many posts.  the command in the Cloud 9 terminal is "sudo apt-get install imagemagick"

once it is installing you will get a message asking => "After this operation, 8852 kB of additional disk space will be used. Do you want to continue? [Y/n]

enter "Y" and you are good to go.

Answer (score 3):

In my case, entering:

`$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick`

resulted in the following response:

> Package imagemagick is not available, but is referred to by another package.
>     This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
>     is only available from another source
>
> E: Package 'imagemagick' has no installation candidate

By first updating the apt-get packages inside the C9 terminal as suggested by **bou2you**:

`$ sudo apt-get update`

I was then able to execute the install imagemagick command-line tools via apt-get:

`$ sudo apt-get install imagemagick`